Is It Possible to Assign Meaningful Amplitudes to Properties in Quantum Mechanics?
In informal discussions of quantum mechanics, it is common to talk about the amplitude for a state to have a certain property. For example, when discussing the double-slit experiment, Feynman states that the amplitude for an electron to arrive at position $x$ on the screen is the sum of the amplitude that it arrives via slit 1 with the amplitude that is arrives via slit 2.
Formally, however, amplitudes are only defined between states. Properties, such as the property that an electron at time $t$ is located within a region $R$, are represented by projection operators. The probability that a state $|\psi \rangle$ exhibits property $P$ is $\langle\psi|P|\psi\rangle$. But at no point does the formalism of Hilbert spaces speak about the amplitude that a state has a property.

My question is whether there is some way to meaningfully assign an amplitude to a property.
Consider a complete, mutually exclusive set of properties $P_1, \ldots, P_n$. That is, $\sum_i P_i = I$ and $P_iP_j = 0$ if $i \ne j$ (which actually follows from the first property). For concreteness, imagine an array of electron detectors on a screen, each represented by a property $P_i = \int_{R_i}\mathrm{d}^2\, |x\rangle\langle x|$, where $R_i$ is the region covered by the detector. In an experiment, we would only be concerned about predicting the probability that a given detector fires; the question of "where" the electron strikes the detector (to the extent that the question is meaningful) is immaterial, since it doesn't impact the observed results.
It is trivial to construct a new Hilbert space that is spanned by the properties $P_i$ — operators are vectors, after all. The question is: can we map a state $|\psi\rangle$ from the original Hilbert space to this new Hilbert space in such a way that we can assign meaningful amplitudes between the state and any property? Specifically, so that $|\langle P_i|\psi'\rangle|^2 = \langle \psi | P_i | \psi \rangle$, where $|\psi'\rangle$ is the mapped state?
My intuition says that this is possible. We routinely ignore the internal details of systems in experiments (as in the detector example above, or when we treat a proton as a point particle instead of a bound state of quarks), and the machinery of quantum mechanics never fails even in this approximate setting.

Edit: Apparently my definition of "property" isn't standard. I've taken it from Robert Griffith's Consistent Quantum Theory:

A quantum property ... is the analog of a collection of points in a classical phase space, and corresponds to a subspace of the quantum Hilbert space, or the projector onto this subspace. An example of a (classical or quantum) property is the statement that the energy $E$ of a physical system lies within some
specific range, $E_0 \le E \le E_1$.

Edit 2: There is one requirement I missed: the amplitude of two mapped states should be preserved: $\langle \phi|\psi\rangle = \langle \phi'|\psi'\rangle$.

You might be interested in reading about the consistent histories approach.

@Andrew I don't see how the consistent histories addresses the question at hand. All the probabilities are computed in terms of projections; the term "amplitude" doesn't even appear in the Wikipedia article

The location of an electron is not a physical property. Only energy, momentum, angular momentum and charges are. The latter are conserved. There is no such thing as a location conservation law. If you are looking for a formula that propagates the location, that's Feynman's path integral.

I disagree with your use of words. "amplitudes are only defined between states", in which case, position "states" are mathematically ill-defined, immediately throwing your definition into trouble. I would also not agree with your definition of property.

Hi Alessandro, Could you elaborate on your second sentence to help me understand how it's a property? I don't see the issue with Feynman's way. I see him calculating the amplitude of the wave function at a specific point $x$ in space after the wave function has propagated from the slits. By the way, I don't need a mathy answer: I'm an experimental physicist.

I thought I was using a standard definition of "property", but apparently not. My definition comes from Robert Griffith's Consistent Quantum Theory and is in the spirit of the consistent histories approach to QM. I've added a clarifying edit.

From a purely mathematical point of view, it can be done for orthogonal projectors $P$ which project onto finite dimensional subspaces. These projectors are Hilbert Schmidt operators exactly as projectors associated to states $Q_\psi= |\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$.
At this juncture,
$$\langle P|Q_\psi\rangle_{HS}:=tr(P^\dagger Q_\psi)=\langle \psi|P\psi\rangle\:.$$
The physical meaning of this approach is however quite dubious to me.

Nice answer, but yeah I do no think this offers much physical information at all. At best it's another way of interpreting the same object.

I agree, indeed.

This answer made me realize that I missed a requirement: the mapped states should preserve their amplitude. i.e. $\langle \phi|\psi\rangle = \langle \phi'|\psi'\rangle$

A possibility arises if you consider operators written in terms of outer products
$$P=\sum_{i,j}|i\rangle\langle j|. $$
The probability of the state $|\psi\rangle$ displaying $P$ is
$$\langle\psi|P|\psi\rangle=\sum_{i,j}\langle\psi|i\rangle\langle j|\psi\rangle=\alpha^*_i \beta_j, $$
where I've written $|\psi\rangle$ as a linear combination of $|n\rangle$ states. In the new Hilbert space we may write $P$ simply as $$|P\rangle= \sqrt{\frac{\alpha_i}{\beta_j}}|j'\rangle,$$
and therefore (simply writing $|\psi\rangle$ in the primed states)
$$|\langle P|\psi'\rangle|^2=\frac{\alpha^*_i}{\beta^*_j}\beta^*_j\beta_j=\alpha^*_i\beta_j .$$

Like the above answer, this made me realize I missed an important requirement: the mapped states should preserve their relative amplitudes. i.e. $\langle \phi|\psi\rangle = \langle \phi'|\psi'\rangle$, in my notation

@AlessandroPower In this example, if you choose a basis $|i'\rangle$ such that $\langle i'|j'\rangle = \langle i|j\rangle$, that condition is also valid.

What Feynman means by the term "amplitude" is probability amplitude, which gives a probability when you compute its modulus square.
So, let's say the initial state is $|\psi\rangle$. The you send this through the double slits toward the screen. This whole process is governed by some unitary operation that we can represent by $\hat{U}$. The state that arrives at the screen is thus given by $\hat{U}|\psi\rangle$. Now, imagine that we can represent the points (or detectors) at different locations on the screen by a coordinate basis $|x\rangle$. Then the "amplitudes" are given by
$$ \mathcal{M}(x) = \langle x|\hat{U}|\psi\rangle . $$
That means that the probability to detect the particle of the original state at $x$ is given by
$$ P(x) = |\mathcal{M}(x)|^2 = |\langle x|\hat{U}|\psi\rangle|^2 . $$
In Feynman view of the sum over histories, the unitary process can be seen as a superposition of all the different "paths" that the "particle" could take to get to the screen. (I put "path" and "particle" in quotation marks because these concepts may not represent physical reality in these scenarios.) So let's say
$$ \hat{U} = \sum_n \hat{Q}_n , $$
where $\hat{Q}_n$ represent the different "paths." So then we get the different amplitudes
$$ \mathcal{M}_n(x) = \langle x|\hat{Q}_n|\psi\rangle . $$
Now the probability becomes
$$ P(x) = \left|\sum_n \mathcal{M}_n(x)\right|^2 . $$
Note that these amplitudes are summed before the modulus square is computed. It allows the possibility for them to interfere.
Although the idea of a particle traveling along different paths (trajectories) to reach the screen may be misleading, it is still valid to say that in general the process can be seen as a superposition of different processes.
